# To what extent should a Hindu follow the rules of a country with a Non-Hindu majority?

Tags: dharma, practice, dharma-shastras

To what extent should a Hindu follow the rules of a country (with a Non-Hindu majority) and where is the limit when a Hindu has to protest or to disobey?

Also, which rights of the Hindu religion should be observed by all countries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tolerance – Other Religions in the Country with a Hindu Majority](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46135/tolerance-other-religions-in-the-country-with-a-hindu-majority)

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda No, this does not answer my question because it is the complementary, and it is closed, too. I regret that Hinduism.SE would not support my project on interreligious tolerance.

Comment: I've cleaned up the tags and also the wording a bit so the focus is on your main question and not your project.

Comment: Thanks thats fine